# How can an Xcode crash report say a function recursively calls itself, when the code has no recursion?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch

Our app crashed, and this is the top of the stack trace:

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x00000001029ddb44 Swift runtime failure: Index out of range + 0 (MyViewModel.swift:0)
1   MyApp                           0x00000001029ddb44 remove + 20 (MyViewModel.swift:202)
2   MyApp                           0x00000001029ddb44 MyViewModel.onPageChanged(index:) + 656
3   MyApp                           0x00000001029ddb38 remove + 8 (MyViewModel.swift:0)
4   MyApp                           0x00000001029ddb38 MyViewModel.onPageChanged(index:) + 644 (MyViewModel.swift:202)
5   MyApp                           0x00000001029d9064 closure #3 in MyView.body.getter + 132 (MyView.swift:45)
6   MyApp                           0x0000000102be07f4 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Int) -> () + 24 (<compiler-generated>:0)
7   MyApp                           0x0000000102be4a60 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Int) -> (@out ()) + 32 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   MyApp                           0x0000000102be0740 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Int) -> () + 24 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   MyApp                           0x0000000102be9f68 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Int) -> (@out ()) + 32 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  MyApp                           0x0000000102bf20e8 partial apply for closure #3 in Pager.PagerContent.body.getter + 60 (PagerContent.swift:208)
11  MyApp                           0x0000000102bd6f24 partial apply for closure #1 in OnAnimationCompletedModifier.notifyCompletionIfFinished() + 60 (OnAnimationCompletedModifier.swift:33)
12  MyApp                           0x0000000102bd6ba4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180dc5924 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180dc7670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180dd5b70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 944 (inline_internal.h:2601)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018110dd84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810c7f5c __CFRunLoopRun + 2540 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810db468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
19  GraphicsServices                0x000000019cc6738c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183a7d088 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3493)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001837fb958 UIApplicationMain + 2092 (UIApplication.m:5046)
22  SwiftUI                         0x0000000188d947a4 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 164 (UIKitApp.swift:35)
23  SwiftUI                         0x0000000188cc3928 runApp<A>(_:) + 252 (<compiler-generated>:0)
24  SwiftUI                         0x0000000188ca50c0 static App.main() + 128 (App.swift:114)
25  MyApp                           0x0000000102969734 $main + 52 (<compiler-generated>:6)
26  MyApp                           0x0000000102969734 main + 64 (MyOtherView.swift:0)
27  dyld                            0x00000001033f5aa4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

This is an index out of bounds exception.

Here's the MyViewModel code:

```swift
    private var shouldPrepareData = true
    ...
    @Published var pagesData = [SomeClass]() {
        didSet {
            if shouldPrepareData {
                shouldPrepareData = false
                ... // this does NOT call onPageChanged anywhere
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    func onPageChanged(index: Int) {
        ...
        pagesData.remove(at: 0) // crashes here!
        ...
    }
```

The exception is caused by removing the first element when the array is empty. Preventing this is trivial and I'm not interested in how to fix it, at least not this line of code.

What I care about is: **how does this stack trace, specifically lines 0 through 4, make sense?** This crash would happen if `pagesData.remove(at: 0)` were called twice when the array had one element, and lines 0 through 4 certainly look like that's happening. But there's nothing in the code that goes from line 3 to line 2. Despite what the stack trace says, obviously `array.remove()` doesn't call `MyViewModel.onPageChanged()`, so how do I make sense of this?

This is happening on thread 0/main, btw. Others have asked what line #5 looks like. It happens in a view that looks like this:

```swift
@StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel();

...

    .onPageChanged { index in // <--- this is defined by a library
        myViewModel.onPageChanged(index: index) // #5
        // log event
     }
```

There is no other place in our code that calls `myViewModel.onPageChanged`.

The outer `onPageChanged` (i.e., the event handler) comes from this library: https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager

Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about swift stack traces, but I don't know what it is. I am more familiar with JavaScript and Java, and it could never print a stack like this. Well, it could, but the array class would need this implementation:

```
Array.remove(int index) {
   // perform logic
   // call Daniel Kaplan's code
}
```

This would be ridiculous, of course. The language's collection library shouldn't/can't directly reference mine. I would assume SwiftUI would be the same, so how can lines 0 through 4 make sense?

---

A comment below says,

> [MyView.]`onPageChanged` (is called whenever the pages index changes) calls viewModel.onPageChanged that manipulates a @Published variable of pages array. It looks recursive to me.

Others have proposed that theory, but if this were the case, I have two followup questions:

1. Since there's no base case, wouldn't this *always* be an infinite loop until it crashes with this error? But this error only occurred once and we can't reproduce it.
2. If `MyView.onPageChanged` is where it recurses, why is it only in the stack trace once?

Comment: Impossible to know with the code you have provided you might be using the index where you display/use pages data. This is a common error when you don’t use one of the apple “safe” ways there is more info on this in Demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC21

Comment: @loremipsum I will watch that video, but since it's 40 minutes long, I'd like to understand what exactly I'm trying to learn from it. Can you give me an example (just one) of what you mean by `apple “safe” ways`? I may already know this, and know it to be unrelated to my question.

Comment: "you might be using the index where you display/use pages data" and if I am, how would that explain the stack trace?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. There is more to it but look around minute 34, this is just a guess there is no way to help you with the code you have provided.

Comment: how `onPageChanged` is called to begin with?

Comment: @KirilS. I edited my answer to put that at the bottom

Comment: @loremipsum I think I understand your hypothesis: view identities might be messed up, and that could have weird side effects. Still, I don't see any way that it could cause a stacktrace like I've reported. It shows that **`remove()`** is calling `.onPageChanged()`. Even with messed up identities, I don't see how the stack would show that.

Comment: What is in `MyView.swift:45)`? and by any chance are you initializing the view model something like `@ObservedObject var vm: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()` if so switch it to `@StateObject` it looks like maybe an animation is causing it?

Comment: @loremipsum I may be misunderstanding the question, but that is line #5. Tomorrow, I'll be able to answer your second question. Thanks for the help

Comment: I see it. Check the state object thing. The Observed object way is leaky. There are specific uses for each the documentation elaborates.

Comment: @loremipsum updated. It's using StateObject. It would help me immensely if you could answer this: Do XCode stack traces hide getters/setters/pub/sub details?

Comment: I usually set them myself body’s are tricky. Swift stacks are nothing like Java stacks there is a “new” self._print….. something that helps with body’s I’ll try to find the exact reference it is an undocumented trace that you can print but an apple dev mentioned it at one of the tech talks. You put it in the body

Comment: `.onPageChanged` (is called whenever the pages index changes) calls `viewModel.onPageChanged` that manipulates a `@Published` variable of pages array. It looks recursive to me.

Comment: @PierreJanineh let's say you're right. 1) There's no base case. Wouldn't this be an infinite loop until it crashes with this error? This error has only occurred once and we can't reproduce it. 2) When you say `.onPageChanged`, I think you mean the one in the view? If that's where it recurses, why is it only in the stack trace once?

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI is-a *reactive world*, we should not think when/if/how modifier called (in majority of cases), we just need to react at that call, and react properly is our responsibility, so to make code safe the guard just should be added (anyway and always), like

```
func onPageChanged(index: Int) {
    if !pagesData.isEmpty && index < pagesData.count {
        pagesData.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

*Why* it is called twice it is a question to Apple, and most probably we never get answer of such question even if they fix sometimes that (rather silently), but you can submit feedback.